# How can i make github search to not show multiple results with the same file name?

Tags: github, search-engine

I have a problem where when i search something in github, there are something 1000 results that are all literally the same file, all the same name, and they are not forks either.

Basically these are just copy pasta codes, and for example i get 1000 results that all end up in xxx.c, which all contain the same code used in different projects..

My question is, is it possible to limit github to only find unique file names? So in our example, only show 1 result that has xxx.c at the end.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is seeking tech support from a specific company.  You need to direct this question to Github support rather than asking it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, from my experience: once you have speficied your criteria from "[Searching Code](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-code)", any file (from different non-fork repositories) would be displayed.

Even though they might be the same name/content.

Comment: So there is literally no way for me to filter these?

Comment: @OneAndOnly Not that I know of, but https://support.github.com/request might have another option (and if they do, come back here to let everybody know)

Comment: @OneAndOnly Did you get an answer from GitHub support?

Comment: Nope, seems like its not possible